# Invoking play on a QTMovie causes screensaver to deactivate on Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime, screensaver

I'm trying to port a working Leopard screensaver to Snow Leopard but it's deactivating after about half a second. The screensaver seems to deactivate upon invoking play on a QTMovie. And it deactivates both upon -play on the QTMovie object itself, and -play:self on the QTMovieView.

If I don't actually call -play on the object, the screensaver does not deactivate and sits still on the first frame of the movie.

Setting up the same code in a regular Cocoa Application works fine, and the screensaver also works fine in preview mode in the System Preferences.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if there's a workaround for this as I've never written a screensaver, but 10.6's QuickTime and ColorSync APIs were both rushed out the door in a fairly unfinished state. I'd ask whether or not this is a known bug on the mailing list if you don't get any bites here: http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/quicktime-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filing a bug report I got the answer that this is a known bug.

Comment: F$%#! As of Jan'12, this is still not fixed. See also http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/SaveHollywood.html

Comment: Still broken in Mountain Lion (10.8.2) in December 2012.